# Deleting migrations results in an Exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, autoload

In my Application, when I run `php artisan migrate:make create_location_user_table`, then delete the generated file (doesn't matter if I delete the line created in `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`, the `php artisan migrate:refresh` command throws an error:

```
include(<path_to_project>/database/migrations/2015_06_21_105357_create_location_user_table.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

After running commands to get rid of the faulty autoload entry, I get an exception. The commands I tried are: `composer update`, `composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan clear-compiled`, `php artisan optimize`.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CreateLocationUserTable' not found in <path_to_project>\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php on line 323

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class 'CreateLocationUserTable' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into your mysql database manually (PHPMyAdmin) and remove the migrations table. With the steps you've taken above and doing this should solve your issue